# Unity : Cast a gameObject as custom monobehavior class

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to cast a gameObject as an instance of a monobehavior class? The gameobject has a script component linked with that very class.

I have an instance of a custom class, called 'HeroUnit', inheriting from monobehavior. I got it by Instantiating a prefab.
I'd like to link this instance to a field of a scriptableobject that expects a 'HeroUnit', but I get an error saying it's a gameObject instead.

So... do I somehow cast my GameObject as a 'HeroUnit'? I can see the gameobject has a 'Script' component associated with my 'HeroUnit' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `GetComponent` answer for this?

```
var _heroUnit = gameObject.GetComponent<HeroUnit>();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Furthermore, GameObjects contain multiple components, so a cast wouldn't fit anyway.